# Export the table to the specified XML format

Tags: c#, xml

I am preparing for an exam from Software Development Fundamentals and I have a question I am not sure about. Could somebody tell me, preferable with some explanation suitable for novice, which code syntax should I use to export given table in specific XML format:

> You need to develop a C# program that exports the contents of the
>   Customers table to an XML file. The exported data must be in the
>   following format:
>
> ```
> <Customer CustomerID="ALFKI" ContactName="Maria Anders" Phone="030-007-4321" /> 
> <Customer CustomerID="ANATR" ContactName="Ana Trujillo" Phone="(5) 555-4729" />
> ```
>
> Which of the following code segments should you use to export the
>   Customers table to the specified XML format?

Select one:

a.

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dataset1.tables["Customers"].Columns)
{
     c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
}
dataSet1.WriteXml("Customers.xml");
```

b.

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dataset1.tables["Customers"].Columns)
{
     c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}
dataSet1.WriteXml("Customers.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

c.

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dataset1.tables["Customers"].Columns)
{
     c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
}
dataSet1.WriteXml("Customers.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

d.

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dataset1.tables["Customers"].Columns)
{
     c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}
dataSet1.WriteXml("Customers.xml");
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ColumnMaping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says how are the data written in the XML. If you choose `Attribute`, the are written as attributes like this

```
<Customer CustomerID="ALFKI" ContactName="Maria Anders" Phone="030-007-4321" />
```

If you choose `Element` it will be written as elemens like this:

```
<Customer>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    ....
</Customer>
```

Two mentioned overloads of `WriteXml` are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms135425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for two arguments overload and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hb27k0tf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for one. Here is the documentation for [`XmlWriteMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.xmlwritemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your case `MappingType.Attribute` must be used and you want to write the data not the schema, so calling `dataSet1.WriteXml("Customers.xml");` is right here.

So I believe that the right answer here is **d**.